# Upper bound of an oscillatory integral

Tags: integration, derivatives, convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, oscillatory-integral

Suppose that $\mathrm{f}:[\mathrm{a}, \mathrm{b}] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth, convex function, and there exists a constant $\mathrm{t}>0$ such that $f^{\prime}(x) \geq t$ for all $x \in(a, b)$. Prove that
$$
\left|\int_a^b e^{i f(x)} d x\right| \leq \frac{2}{t}
$$

I tried to use some of the properties from the oscillatory integral and wrote the integrand as $f^{\prime}(x) e^{i f(x)} / f^{\prime}(x)$ but it seems there is some fundamental idea missing in my attempts.

Comment: try writing the integrand as $f'(x)e^{if(x)}/f'(x)$ and see if it helps

Comment: @tomos Thank you for the suggestion. That's also what I did, my bad for not mentioning it in the post. Unfortunately, it didn't lead to any fruitful results.

Comment: Notice that 
\begin{align}
e^{i f(x)} = \frac{1}{i f'(x)}\frac{d}{d x}e^{i f(x)}
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
\int^b_a e^{i f(x)} d x = \int^b_a \frac{1}{i f'(x)}\frac{d}{d x}e^{i f(x)} d x.
\end{align}
Then integration by parts. Finally, estimate your way to success.

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks for the idea, but integration by parts doesn't lead to results as far as I try because of the second derivative of $f(x)$ that comes to play. Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using integration by parts and noting that $f'(x) \geq t > 0$ and $f''(x) \geq 0$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \int_{a}^{b} e^{if(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \right|
&= \left| \frac{e^{if(b)}}{if'(b)} - \frac{e^{if(a)}}{if'(a)} + \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f''(x)}{if'(x)^2}e^{if(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{f'(b)} + \frac{1}{f'(a)} + \int_{a}^{b} \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq \frac{1}{f'(b)} + \frac{1}{f'(a)} + \left[ \frac{1}{f'(a)} - \frac{1}{f'(b)} \right] \\
&= \frac{2}{f'(a)}
\leq \frac{2}{t}.
\end{align*}

*Remark.* This bound cannot be improved further by noting that the equality holds if $f$ is linear with slope $t$ and $t(b - a)$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I wanted to ask how you get $e^{if(x)}$ is less than $i$ in modulus expression. It seems you have applied this rule to every part of the triangle inequality so I was wondering how it could be proved.

Comment: @Snowball No problem. Note that $|e^{iy}|=1$ for *any* real $y$ as well as $|i|=1$. Now you mix this with the triangle inequality.